# How can I write installation path to registry with custom delimiter in WiX?

Tags: wix

I would like to write a value to registry which consists of installation path and some additional path. Delimiter must be '/', e.g.

```
Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]/folder1/folder2"
```

How can I format this value so that installation path will be also with '/' delimiter instead of '\'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI formatting doesn't support this. You'd have to write a custom action that read the property, reformatted the string and wrote it to a new property ( INSTALLLOCATIONFORMATTED)   then you could use that property in the Registry table.

The bigger question and simpler answer though is .... "why?"

Are you doing something like file://c:/foo/bar.txt  ?

file://C:\foo\bar.txt should work also as \ is the standard on the Windows Platform.   It's probably better that whatever code reads this registry value be modified to accept \ instead of /.   This results in a simpler and less fragile installer.

Comment: Thanks. The value is intended for third-party tool which requires this kind of delimiter.

Comment: Sounds like they should fix their stuff or you should choose another third party tool. :)  (Yes, I am that militant about good design.)

Comment: That has some historical background. It comes from ages when this software was running in unix. At some point functionality was moved to windows side, but the separator remained.

Comment: Sure, I could see that coming and hence why I wrote "\ is the standard on the Windows Platform".  I see this kind of thing all the time when developers switch stacks and don't understand the new stack and do things like they always have.  The cleaner solution is to fix that problem and have the code that reads the registry value to guard it's inputs and transpose \ to / if needed internally.  It shouldn't be an installer problem to make it work to a non-standard spec.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen similar problems with the case of directories and files. In those cases I just tell the developer that Windows is case aware but not case sensitive.

Comment: You're right. The tool should support \ delimiter too. Let's see what developer  will say. :) Thanks.